# Sonos Authorization API - Client Credentials

Tags: sonos

Is there a maximum limit of client credentials my control integration can use ?
I would like to control the sonos devices via a small IOT device that has it's own event callback URL without using an external server. 
Is this possible ?

In the client credentials I can only configure one event callback url. 
I would build a tiny webservice in the IOT device that receives event callbacks for status changes. (Volume changes / Playback states / group states)
Every IOT device needs a different callback url (and different client credentials).
Is this possible ?

If this is possible can we use a self-signed certificate for our IOT webservice ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a maximum limit of client credentials my control integration
>   can use?

There's no maximum limit. But note that your application uses the API key and secret, not the customer, therefore you should not need more than one. You don't need to create a unique API key and secret for each customer. You may need to create multiple credentials if you wish to have a one for your development app and one for your production app.

> I would like to control the sonos devices via a small IOT device that
>   has it's own event callback URL without using an external server. Is
>   this possible?

We do not currently support a redirect URI to a local device or app (for example - a Redirect URI that opens an app on the device).